# Reassembly error, protocol TCP: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)

Tags: tcp, https, proxy, wireshark

I wrote a proxy server which support http and https connection, When I use with http all work fine, but when I work with https , wireshark report this error
'Reassembly error, protocol TCP: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)'
Although the browsing work fine but performance is impacted as after this I see TCP RST and because of that SSL negotiation happen again.

Any clue on what could be wrong ?

```
169.254.119.252 169.254.1.66    TCP 66  54589 > ff-fms [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
169.254.1.66    169.254.119.252 TCP 60  ff-fms > 54589 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=16384 Len=0 MSS=1456
169.254.119.252 169.254.1.66    TCP 54  54589 > ff-fms [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65520 Len=0
169.254.119.252 169.254.1.66    TCP 245 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
169.254.1.66    169.254.119.252 TCP 912 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
169.254.119.252 169.254.1.66    TCP 252 54588 > ff-fms [PSH, ACK] Seq=192 Ack=859 Win=64662 Len=198[Reassembly error, protocol TCP: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)]
169.254.1.66    169.254.119.252 TCP 91  [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
169.254.119.252 169.254.1.66    TCP 54  54587 > ff-fms [RST, ACK] Seq=391 Ack=955 Win=0 Len=0
```